# Does <s:button> support reRender with <a4j:support>

Tags: ajax, richfaces, seam

SSIA

Can I use `<s:button>` with `<a:support>`?

I can't seem to make it work.

```
<h:panelGroup id="pwgen">
    <s:decorate template="/layout/definition.xhtml" rendered="#{s:hasRole('sysadmin')}">
        <ui:define name="label">#{messages['manualOnetimePassword']}</ui:define>
        <s:button  value="#{messages['generate']}" propagation="join" action="#{userAdmin.generateManualPasswordForUser()}">
            <a:support event="onsubmit" reRender="pwgen" ajaxSingle="true" />
        </s:button>
        <h:inputText size="30" required="false" value="#{userAdmin.existingUser.manualPassword.password}"/>
    </s:decorate>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I have tried `<a:outputPanel>` and `<a:region>` and also `event="oncomplete"` but it always reloads the entire page.

Comment: Shervin, why dou you prefer <s:button> ? For propagation property?

Comment: Well only because I didn't want to POST, because I was inside a larger form. However I can see that by changing the code to use a4j:button it pretty much solves everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

It doesn't seem that `<s:button>` supports `<a:support>`.

All I did basically is changed the button to be `<a:commandButton reRender="foo">` and removing the `<a:support>`

Answer (score 0):

Because s:button and s:link dont post your form. So, there are no 'onsubmit' event. Yes, replace it with a4j:commandButton :)